# Creating a deeply nested dictionary from a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, tree

I am creating a multi level nested dictionary by reading from a large csv file. The content the files are in the following format, which store relevant information pertaining a unique book. We can assume each row has 6 columns(author, title, year, category, url, citations); all column entries have identical formatting. For example:

```
Author,Title,Year,Category,Url,Citations
"jk rowling, etc....",goblet of fire,1973,magic: fantasy: english literature,http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066,6
"Weiner, Leonard H.",cracking the coding interview,1973,LA: assessment: other,http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808105,2
"Tolkien",hobbit,1953,magic: fantasy: medieval,http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066,6
```

I want the output to match how each row in the csv file is parsed, similar to the following:
*(note: the # of nested dictionaries is dependent on the book categories under the category header of the csv. Keys are based on successive categories (order matters), separated by the ':' delimiter. Think of the ordering of categories per row in the csv file as the path directory; multiple files can have the same path directory up to a certain point or they can have the same path directory and be placed in the same folder.

```
results = {'1973':{
    "magic": {
        "fantasy": {
            "English literature": {
                "name": "goblet of fire",
                "citations": 6,
                "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066"
            }
        },
        "medieval": {
            "name": "The Hobbit",
            "citations": 7,
            "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800fdfdffd010.808066"
        }
       }
    },
    '1953':{
    "la": {
        "assessment": {
            "other": {
                "name": "cracking the coding interview",
                "citations": 6,
                "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808105"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Obviously some books will have share common successive categories together like in the example I showed above. Some books might also share the exact same successive categories. I think I should recursively iterate through the string of categories per row in the csv, either creating new sub dicts that deviate from a preexisting category order, then creating a dictionary representation of the book once there are no more successive categories to check. I'm just not sure exactly how to start.

Here's what I have so far, it's just a standard setup of reading csv files:

```
  with open(DATA_FILE, 'r') as data_file:
        data = csv.reader(data_file)
```

Essentially, I want to create a tree representation of this csv using nested dictionaries, the relative category path (i.e. magic:fantasy:etc...), determining which subtree to traverse/create.If two or more books have the same consecutive path, I want to make all those books leafs of their respective key, instead of overriding each book(leaf) whenever a new book has an identical category path. Leafs represent a dictionary representation of the books mentioned per row in the csv.

Answer (score 2):

You can group your data by category (using a simple dictionary, as you mentioned that you cannot use any modules other than `csv`) and then apply recursion:

```
import csv
_, *data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
new_data = [[i[3].split(': '), *i[4:], *i[:3]] for i in data]
def group(d):
  _d = {}
  for a, *b in d:
    if a[0] not in _d:
      _d[a[0]] = [[a[1:], *b]]
    else:
      _d[a[0]].append([a[1:], *b])
  r = {a:{'books':[{'name':c[-2], 'citations':c[2], 'url':c[1], 'author':c[3]} for c in b if not c[0]], **(lambda x:{} if not x else group(x))([c for c in b if c[0]])} for a, b in _d.items()}
  return {a:{c:d for c, d in b.items() if d} for a, b in r.items()}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(group(new_data), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
  "magic": {
    "fantasy": {
        "english literature": {
            "books": [
                {
                    "name": "goblet of fire",
                    "citations": "6",
                    "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066",
                    "author": "jk rowling, etc...."
                }
            ]
        },
        "medieval": {
            "books": [
                {
                    "name": "hobbit",
                    "citations": "6",
                    "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066",
                    "author": "Tolkien"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"LA": {
    "assessment": {
        "other": {
            "books": [
                {
                    "name": "cracking the coding interview",
                    "citations": "2",
                    "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808105",
                    "author": "Weiner, Leonard H."
                }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Edit: grouping by publication date:

```
import csv
_, *data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
new_data = [[i[3].split(': '), *i[4:], *i[:3]] for i in data]
_data = {}
for i in new_data:
  if i[-1] not in _data:
    _data[i[-1]] = [i]
  else:
    _data[i[-1]].append(i)

final_result = {a:group(b) for a, b in _data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{
 "1973": {
    "magic": {
        "fantasy": {
            "english literature": {
                "books": [
                    {
                        "name": "goblet of fire",
                        "citations": "6",
                        "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066",
                        "author": "jk rowling, etc...."
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "LA": {
        "assessment": {
            "other": {
                "books": [
                    {
                        "name": "cracking the coding interview",
                        "citations": "2",
                        "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808105",
                        "author": "Weiner, Leonard H."
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
 },
 "1953": {
    "magic": {
        "fantasy": {
            "medieval": {
                "books": [
                    {
                        "name": "hobbit",
                        "citations": "6",
                        "url": "http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800010.808066",
                        "author": "Tolkien"
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I keep receiving '"index Error: list index out of range" when implementing the first snippet?

Comment: @KaiLee Please post the data you are using that is raising that error.

Comment: i posted the snippet

Comment: @KaiLee Please see my recent edit.

Comment: damn, I am still getting list index out of range errors .

Comment: @KaiLee Strange, it is working fine for me. Please create a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/), add the contents of your entire file, and post the link as a comment. I will take a look at it and see what can be done.

Comment: thank you so much! [link](https://gist.github.com/Theyoungkai/099e3c0f0151102f0739ae765ef969c6)

Comment: @KaiLee Thank you very much. The `IndexError` is because there is a major edge case in your data: some book categories have both regular book listings associated with it, along with other child categories, both of which need to be included in the data. As such, I added an additional key to the final result, `"books"`. This key stores all the books associated with the parent category and still enables child categories to be included as well. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: thank you so much! ONe last thing if you don't mind, can you also add the books 'authors' as another key value pair in the final dictionary(ie:leaf), so i would have access to the books authors, name, url and citations?

Comment: @KaiLee No problem. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: If I were to order the nested dictionary based on the publication date( ie: the publication date would be the first key of every dictionary of  depth 1, then followed by the same ordering as the prior solution for subtrees or depth >=2, how would i do such?

Comment: @KaiLee Are you simply trying to add the publication date to the dictionary along with `name`, `url`, `citation` etc, or are you trying to group the books by publication date? If you are trying to accomplish the latter, please post your desired output.

Comment: for example, if two books were siblings from the previous version ( since they share identical category paths), they wouldn't necessarily be siblings in this version if they don't share the same publication date.

Comment: I have edited in the desired output in the original question as desired.

Comment: @KaiLee Thank you, sorry for the late response. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @KaiLee If this answer has helped you, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate categories by their nest
2. Parse CSV to pandas dataframe
3. Groupby by category in a loop
4. use to_dict() to convert to dict in a groupby loop

Comment: i can't use any dependencies just built-in methods/data structures. The only module i can use is csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv', sep=',')
```

Next, you want to isolate the `Category` column and split its content with columns:

```
cols_no_categ = list(df.columns)
cols_no_categ.remove('Category')
category = df['Category']
DICT = {}
for c in category:
    dicto = df[df.Category == c, cols_no_categ].to_dict()
    s = c.split(': ')
    DICT[s[0]][s[1]][s[2]] = dicto
```